# What is the recommended why of using derby.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, derbyjs

I'm trying to figure out how to install and use derby.js.
I have installed node.js version: 0.8.17
I have cloned derby from github, and installed, version: 0.3.13
I have installed derby-examples, also version 0.3.13

The examples don't really work.. the page renders but nothing dynamic happens.

What am I doing wrong?
What is the correct why of working with derby? should I install with the package available with npm, or do I need to use github?

I can't make it to work... going crazy

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone:

I managed to solve my problems after finding this wiki-page:
https://github.com/codeparty/derby/wiki/Using-Derby-%22Edge%22

Answer (score 0):

From version 0.5 you can just use npm version.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble too until I encountered https://github.com/derbyparty/generator-derby

Try running this with all the advanced options turned off, it gives a nice working starting point for new Derby projects. There is no dynamic behavior though, you'll need to add that yourself. I found that a good starting point is modifying the app based on the steps explained in this Multi-Player Notepad video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0DOGXmaT3g